# *Highcharts* Tooltip formatter for a combined chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

I have a combine percent column and line chart with two y axis. The column chart I use absolute value to draw and the line chart I use percent value, and I have a tooltip like this:

```
pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y})<br/>',
shared: true
```

When I use this tooltip, it shows the correct format for my percent column chart: percent value (absolute value) but wrong format for line chart which shows something like: 0.0%( percent value). How can I format my tooltip so that it can show the percent value for the percent column chart like its showing but in the line chart it shows only the value at this point which is already a percent value.

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3d406av3/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `tooltip.pointFormat` on a series level: http://jsfiddle.net/3d406av3/3/

For example:

```
{
    type:'line',
    name: 'Suzo',
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: </span>{point.y}<br/>',
    },
    yAxis:1,
    data: [123, 11, 14, 66, 44]
}
```